# absoluted text position underneath text avoiding overlap

Tags: html, css

The span colored with yellow background covers the text underneath. How to avoid the overlapping and make it looks like that as if the span is inserted after the word "reliable" in pre tag.

The problem is shown on this jsfiddle [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/pzyw5uLy/).
The expected result looks like [`this`](http://jsfiddle.net/pzyw5uLy/4/) , but don't embed the span tag into the tag pre.

If the formatted text in tag  can't be separated into several  tags, how to resolve the issue?

Comment: The expected result link and the original jsfiddle link both are showing the same output. Can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve here ?

Comment: My last update was not saved. Now, it shouldn't look same.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `<span></span>` inside the `<pre>` tag.

```
<pre>
    Forget the foosball table and a decent coffee machine; the thing staff most want from their employers is a fast and reliable information technology system, according to an international survey.

<span>NO-OVERLAY</span>

    The research was carried out by London-listed multinational Regus which provides serviced offices and meeting rooms for business people.
</pre>
```

Also, change your CSS to this:

```
pre {
white-space: pre-wrap;
}
span {
    background: yellow;
    margin-left: 90px;
}
```

See the fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/zuhgs54h/